# Multiple robots meta tags

Tags: meta, robots.txt

I've recently inherited a codebase and discovered this gem:

```
{% if PAGE_EXTRAS.hide_from_sitemap %}
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
{% endif %}
```

I have no idea what it's trying to do. Is there a reason you'd put multiple, apparently-conflicting robots tags in a site like that? Or is it as insane as it looks to my uninformed eye?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a mistake to me. The only information I could find about this was in [Google's Robots meta tag specification](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag):

> If competing directives are encountered by our crawlers we will use the most restrictive directive we find.

So, (for Google, at least) the code:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
<meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

does exactly the same thing as:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

It's conceivable this code *might* be intended as some sort of sneaky hack, intended to apply different rules to different crawlers by exploiting differences in how they resolve conflicts. If so, this is a terrible idea, IMHO. There is no need for a messy fragile hack when there's already a legitimate mechanism to do the same thing:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, follow">
<meta name="bingbot" content="index, nofollow">
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!